# Passing multiple arguments to SQLite via Ant

Tags: sqlite, ant

I need to use both .separator and .import when calling SQLite from my Ant script but can't seem to get the syntax right. Based on an answer here on SO about doing the same in a bash script, my latest attempt is this.

```
<exec executable="sqlite3">
    <arg value="${sqlite.db}" />
    <arg value=".separator ';'\n.import ${data.dir}/DISTRICT_BOUNDARY.txt DISTRICT_BOUNDARY" />
</exec>
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error message.

Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "separator". Enter ".help" for help

What is the proper syntax for what I am trying to do?

**Final solution:**

```
<exec executable="sqlite3" inputstring=".separator ';'&#10;.import ${data.dir}/METADATA_DESCRIPTION.txt METADATA_DESCRIPTION">
    <arg value="${sqlite.db}" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Your script sample isn't displaying.  Could you also include a link to the SO answer you referred to ?

Comment: I can't seem to find the other thread now, very odd. I am still having trouble with this and can't even get it to work on the command line. Any help on importing a ; delimited file into SQLite from the command line and/or Ant is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can't pass meta-commands (i.e., commands that start with a `.`) via the final argument to sqlite3; only actual SQL statements seem to work there[*]. There are two possible fixes; either write the meta-commands to a file and use the `-file filename` option (two arguments, before database name) to load them, or pass the whole multi-statement set of instructions in on sqlite3's standard input. This second option should be simpler for you to implement with ant, via the `inputstring` parameter:

```
<exec executable="sqlite3" inputstring=".separator ';'
.import ${data.dir}/DISTRICT_BOUNDARY.txt DISTRICT_BOUNDARY">
    <arg value="${sqlite.db}" />
</exec>
```

Yes, that has a real newline in it. Unlike real SQL statements, you can't separate meta-commands with semicolons. You may encode the newline as `&#10;` if you wish.

---

[*] Actually, a single meta-command would work, but you can't put two.

Comment: If you're really unlucky, ant will munge the attribute with a newline in it. It shouldn't happen — it would be a bug in ant — but I don't trust “shouldn't” too much and I can't test right now. If that does bite, you're stuck loading a file containing the meta-commands to execute…

Comment: Thank you! A couple of notes. In my version of sqlite (3.7.7), the argument for using commands in a file is `-init`, not `-flag`. That worked very well, but due to the need for dynamic pathing would have been kind of a pain in my scenario.

I also couldn't get it to work with the newlines, so I am using`&#10;`

Comment: @bclinkinbeard Glad it worked, sorry there wasn't anything better. (A lot of XML parsers aren't even close to conformant…)

Answer (score 0):

I think Ant is interpreting the single quotes in your second arg value as string delimiters.  Try escaping the single quotes:

```
<arg value=".separator \';\'\n.import${data.dir}/DISTRICT_BOUNDARY.txt DISTRICT_BOUNDARY" />
```

I'm not familiar with SQLite syntax, but the .import parameter may also need to be a separate arg value.